# Populate Textbox from Listbox Selection | Windows 7 Phone

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, listbox, populate

**Question:**

Simply, What is the best/most simple way for pre-defined items in a Listbox

(Such as *"Bob"*)

to be populated into a TextBox In a Windows 7 Phone Enviroment?

**Example:**

If I select *"Bob"* from the list box - then *"Bob"* should then be displayed in the text box instantly

(so the user doesn't need to type in a Username)

..and they can instead use a pre-made username from the list of Usernames.

**Problems:**

- I've tried looking for these little things and found no solutions.
- The solutions I did find are incredibly vague.
- Many videos on YouTube and elsewhere haven't really covered this for Windows 7
- I fear Windows 8 Mobile is different.
- Right now, my code fails to populate the Textbox with the Listbox Selection.
- Relatively new programmer, trying to find my feet in c#

**Code:**

I don't really know how to do this. I've tried using a built in feature called SelectionChanged but to no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Class

```
public class Movie
{
   public string Actor { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Create a List of Movie with the Data .

```
public class MovieList : List<Movie>
{
   public MovieList()
   {
     Add(new Movie { Name = "Titanic", Actor = "xxx", });
     Add(new Movie { Name = "LordOFtheRings", Actor = "yyyy",  });
   }
}
```

In XAML,

```
<ListBox Height="596" Name="listBox1" Width="380" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In your code behind.cs

```
 public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   FillListBox();
}

private void FillListBox()
{
   listBox1.ItemsSource = new MovieList();
}
```

Your Textbox should be

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```